# What is the most general solution of the following functional equations?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-equations, functional-calculus

$f, F:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}^+$ such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)=1\\
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x)=1\\
2\pi\int_x^\infty tF(t) dt =f(x)\\
f(x)f(y)f(z) = F(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

where in the last equation, $x, y, z$ are independent variables (like Cartesian coordinates, maybe).

This comes up in solving Maxwell-Boltzmann’s distribution. And a solution is $$f(x) = Ae^{Bx^2}$$ where $A, B$ are arbitrary real constants.

My question is whether there is a more general solution to the above system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the conditions force $f,F$ to be smooth outside zero at least.

Define $g(x)=\ln{f}(\sqrt{x})$. Then there exists a continuous $G$ such that for positive $x,y,z$, $G(x+y+z)=g(x)+g(y)+g(z)$. Therefore, $G(x)=3g(x/3)$, hence $\frac{g(x)+g(y)+g(z)}{3}$ depends only on $x+y+z$.

You can conclude that for any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the quantity $g_1(r)=g(a)-g(b)$ does not depend on the couple $(a,b)$ of positive real numbers such that $a-b=r$, and $g_1$ is smooth, and $g_1(x)=g(2x)-g(x)=g(3x)-g(2x)$.

We also have $g_1(x)+g_1(y)+g_1(z)$ depending only on $x+y+z$, and by definition $g_1$ is odd. It follows that $g_1$ is linear. Now, $g(x)=g_1(x-1)+g(1)$, so $g$ is affine, Q.E.D.

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth outside zero"?

Comment: By stating it to be affine, how can you Q.E.D. that it is the most general solution?

Comment: I am showing that $g$ must be affine. This corresponds to $f(x)=Ae^{Bx^2}$ for some $A,B>0$, for all positive $x$. Then you use continuity of $f$ and the functional equation again to show $f$ is even and that the equality works at $x=0$.

Comment: Smooth outside $0$: smooth on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: But is there a more general solution than $Ae^{Bx^2}$?